# How to change login form Lost Password button into a hyperlink in web2py?

Tags: authentication, web2py

The Lost Password button is added to the default login form via:

```
<div id="web2py_user_form">
{{
...
    if not 'request_reset_password' in auth.settings.actions_disabled:
        form.add_button(T('Lost Password'),
                        URL(args='request_reset_password'),
                        _class='btn')
    pass
...
=form
}}
```

How can I change this from a button to an html hyperlink instead?  Also preferably I'd want the link on a separate line from the "Login" and "Register" buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok by looking at the source code for add_button I figured out how to do this:

```
<div id="web2py_user_form">
{{
...
    if not 'request_reset_password' in auth.settings.actions_disabled:
        submit_button = form.element('input[type=submit]')
        submit_button.parent.append(DIV(A(T('Lost Password'),
                                   _href=URL(args='request_reset_password'))))
    pass
...
=form
}}
```